# importing a file and using the data within the file to rename it

Tags: python, function, file

```py
import os
def new_names(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.read()
        sted = lines.split('\n',1)[0]
        dato = lines.split('\n',1)[1]
        os.rename('qwghlm.txt',"{dato}_{sted}.txt")
    return (filename)
print(new_names('qwghlm.txt'))
```

The task is to take the file `qwghlm.txt and get information from the first two lines within the file, areas and dates. Then rename the file with the new areas and dates, however the only output i get from this is the file name. Is the because the code is worse then i thought or because of some other file extracting problems?
the variable filename is just a stand in as the code is supposed to rename multible files

the expected output is to rename the file "date_place.txt" and the rest of the data should still be stored in the file.

the actual ouput is my computer just printing the old name and not actually renaming the file

Comment: That's the output you print ..

Comment: Can you please clarify what the problem is? Your code seems to work, it renames the file (though are probably missing an `f` in front of the new name: `f"{dato}_{sted}.txt"`). What kind of output are you expecting? Please read [mcve] and include the expected output.

Comment: It's also a bit peculiar that you let `new_names` take an argument `filename`, but then don't use it in the `os.rename` call.

Comment: The variable `filename` actually doesn't change when you renamed the file. So your function actually just returns the variable it got when it was called.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking in a right direction. You have two main problems: a) string is not interpolated (variables are not substituted with values) and b) `dato` contains all file content except first line, it there is more than 2 lines.

```py
import os
def new_names(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        # Don't read whole file
        sted = f.readline().strip('\n')
        dato = f.readline().strip('\n')
    
    # note 'f' prefix
    new_name = f"{dato}_{sted}.txt"
    # Close the file before renaming
    # And don't hardcode file name here, why?
    os.rename(filename, new_name)
    return new_name

print(new_names('qwghlm.txt'))
```

Comment: I have added your improvements, however i now get a permission error, the process does not have access to the file as it is being used by a different process. I have also added filename as a variable that include the two "oldfiles" that have to be renamed.

Comment: Have you moved `os.rename` outside of `with open...` block? If yes, then, probably, it is not problem with this solution, but your file remains open for some reason (maybe some other process keeps owning it). Try rebooting first, if you're on windows - AFAIR, it helps often. I can run this successfully on my machine.

Comment: i had not moved it outside of with open, ill do that and reboot thank you